# Polymer website not opening on ios Safari or Chrome

Tags: ios, iphone, polymer-1.0

The website I've been creating on http://chrisgiffy.github.com won't open on iOS with either Chrome or Safari

I'm not able to find out what the issue is. All I get in return is a blank page.

Can someone help me on this or show me how to debug on the device?

Comment: That's how it looks from my browser.

Comment: On the computer it looks fine im having an issue on apple mobile

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: again this is only for android i guess as from ios iphone i cannot enable this

Comment: the site works perfectly on android and pc

Answer (score 2):

On IOS 9.3.2 I have discovered that Polymer paper-fab.. has an affect on rendering the page.

If you are using that component, then try removing it (hoping someone can fork a new version.)